# Finding the Owner of An Active Directory Group

Tags: windows, active-directory, directory

How can I find the owner of an Active Directory group?
Not by writing programming code - I am interested if it is possible to find it over some iterface.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Active Directory Users and Computers:

- Find the group in question
- Right-click and Select Properties
- Selected the Security tab
- Click the Advanced button
- Select the Owner tab

You should then see the owner of the group.

Comment: "Active Directory Users and Computers" program does not exist in my computer. I am using Windows 7. How can I find/istall it?

Comment: (it is a client computer, NOT server)

Comment: To acces that program from a client you need to install the Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7887). This all assumes you have permissions though, which looks suspect to me. Why don't you just look on the server? I can't see any reason to want to find out the owner of a group without code being more than just a one off activity.

Comment: I have installed the software. However I can't find the program "Active Directory Users and Computers" in All Programms. Is this the place I need to search? (I do not which server I have to use - it would be more convenient to me if I could see it from my client computer. Do not understand why that so complicated is. if all colleagues from the company would access the server to find the owner, that does not seem so elegant to me... I would prefer the other way, where I can find the owner from local computer)